# Track method execution time in worker service with application insight custom metric

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I am looking for to track multiple methods(A=>B=>C) execution time with application insight custom metric.
From the [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service)
I can get the execution stats for the main worker process, but is there any way I can also get the execution time of dependency methods calls also in application insight ?

Comment: Have you had a chance to check the provided solution?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the same [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service#dependencies), dependency collection is enabled by default. While there are many dependencies that are automatically collected, you can still track one manually with a [TrackDependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#trackdependency) call if it isn't auto-collected.

App Insights measures the **duration** of dependency calls, whether its failing or not, along with additional information like name of dependency and so on. The collected data can be found in Application Map, Transaction diagnostics, or queried from Log Analytics.

Example:

[image: Example]

This should enable you to investigate specific dependency calls and also correlate them to requests and exceptions. Dependency Tracking in Azure Application Insights is explained in great detail in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies) article.